# Return the cursor to view after selecting range

Tags: microsoft-excel

Sometimes when I'm entering a formula in edit mode directly in the cell, I have to select a large range of cells which results in the screen scrolling to show the edge of the selected range. This moves the edited cell out of view. What is the easiest way to get the edited cell back into view? I can hit the F4 key and this will bring the cell back into view, but sometimes I have to hit the key 3 more times since I wanted relative references to begin with. I can also type in a comma after I select the range and hit an arrow key. This will bring the cell back into view, but now have to delete a cell reference. Is there any way to bring a cell in edit mode back into view with just a flashing cursor after selecting the range?

Comment: Why do you want to see the target cell while constructing the formula?

Comment: You can click in the space above the vertical scrollbar (or to the left of the horizontal scrollbar) to jump by "pages".  Unless the range you selected is enormous, it will only take a few clicks to return to where you were.